# Swift and Javascript Integration

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

i was following along [this article](http://www.kinderas.com/technology/2014/6/15/wkwebview-and-javascript-in-ios-8-using-swift) about integrating **Swift (WKWebView) and Javascript.** Everything from the article works fine but i am trying to pass some variable from Swift to Javascript.

This is my ViewController in Swift:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKScriptMessageHandler {

    @IBOutlet var containerView : UIView! = nil
    var webView: WKWebView?

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        let contentController = WKUserContentController();
        let userScript = WKUserScript(
            source: "redHeader()",
            injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd,
            forMainFrameOnly: true
        )
        contentController.addUserScript(userScript)
        contentController.addScriptMessageHandler(
            self,
            name: "callbackHandler"
        )

        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.userContentController = contentController

        self.webView = WKWebView(
            frame: self.view.frame,
            configuration: config
        )
        self.view = self.webView!
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = NSURL(string:"https://example.com")
        let req = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)
        self.webView!.loadRequest(req)

        let simpleInt = 123

        self.webView?.evaluateJavaScript("redHeader(\(simpleInt)", completionHandler: nil);
    }

    func userContentController(userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceiveScriptMessage message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if(message.name == "callbackHandler") {
            print("JavaScript is sending a message \(message.body)")
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

and thats the **HTML and JS** residing on an server:

```css
function callNativeApp () {
    try {
        webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage("Hello from JavaScript");
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('The native context does not exist yet');
    }
}

setTimeout(function () {
    callNativeApp();
}, 50000);

function redHeader(int) {
 console.log(int);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                padding-top: 40px; 
            }
        </style>
        <title>WKWebView Demo</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>WKWebView Test</h1>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's still just the code from the above article but i am not able to pass the variable **simpleInt** to the JS.

Despite that the Javascript call

```
webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage("Hello from JavaScript");
```

does not work as well.

I think I am passing the variable wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can try out

1. window is missing from your method call

   ```
   webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage("Hello from JavaScript");
   ```

   should be

   `window.webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage("Hello from JavaScript");`
2. Check if you are able to access message handler from browser open debug menu for this [Check for enabling debug mode](http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/)

   `window.webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler`

[image: Result]

3. One more issue might be using timeout with native call. Remove timeout and add a button to call messageHandler.